# Why is my javascript file not recognizing servlet like jsp does?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, fetch

I have a servlet named like

`@WebServlet("/UserServlet")`, and when I use `action="UserServlet"` on JSP, it recognizes it, but the JavaScript file does not.
File Path Info:
Servlet is located at `src/main/java/com.name.controller/UserServlet`.
JSPs located at `webapp/view/`
JavaScript file lcoated at `webapp/js/`

When I do this:

```
    fetch('/UserServlet', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: registrationDataJSON
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // handle success or error response
            if (data.status === 'success') {
                // redirect to home page or display success message
            } else {
                // display error message
                alert(data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            // handle network or server error
            console.error(error);
        });
    return true;
};
```

This redirects to `localhost:8080/UserServlet` instead of `localhost:8080/ProjectName/UserServlet`.

But when I mention full path to servlet like this:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/projectname/UserServlet', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: registrationDataJSON
    }
```

Then it works, Is there no way I can make it work simply using the Servlet Name and not full path?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), the first parameter it uses an [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object which you have to build yourself.

```
let base_url = 'http://localhost:8080/projectname';
fetch(base_url+'/UserServlet', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: registrationDataJSON
    }
```

If you don't want to hardcode the base URL, then you can get it either from server or from the [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object property. The `window.location.origin` may be used for the base URL.